# Stop infinite loop reactive forms control update in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have 2 inputs on a form, a numeric input called "ageMonths", and a date selector called "dateOfBirth".

I want the user to be able to enter either months for an age, or use the date selector to pick a Date of Birth (dob). If they enter a dob from the date selector, I want the month field to update to the age in months. If they enter an age in months, I want the date selector to jump to that date. I'm using reactive forms.

I added a class level variable to hold a toggle which is read and set each time a value changes for either control. But this isn't working as expected, I assume due to events not firing in the order I am expecting them to.

What do I need to do to make this work?

My code is:

```
ignoreDateUpdate = false;
form: FormGroup;
...
constructor(...){
this.form = new FormGroup({
    dateOfBirth: new FormControl({ value: new Date()}),
    ageMonths: new FormControl({ value: 0 }),
    ...
});
...
this.form.get('ageMonths').valueChanges.subscribe(
m => {
    if (ignoreDateUpdates) {return};
    ignoreDateUpdates = true;
    <code to set DateSelectorValue>
    ignoreDateUpdates = false;
    });
this.form.get('dateOfBirth').valueChanges.subscribe(
dob => {
    if (ignoreDateUpdates) {return};
    ignoreDateUpdates = true;
    <code to set MonthsInput>
    ignoreDateUpdates = false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm answering this as I've got the required behaviour by adding the `{emitEvent: false}` option to my setValue calls:

```
const calcDate = <calculate date from months value>;
this.form.get('dateOfBirth').setValue(calcDate, { emitEvent: false });
```

But I'd still like to know why the toggle field didn't work as expected if anyone can explain?

Comment: This helped me find what I needed related to this ... specifically hydrating updated data from return call to an update function. Sometimes you need to get that new data in the form model but don't want it to fire `valueChanges` else the update loops. For me using `this.formRef.form.patchValue(someObject, { emitEvent: false })` was the magic sauce!

Comment: Thanks!! It works!! I'd like to know better this mechanism too

Answer (score 1):

i also implemented this kind of functionality in my app,i have two input box one is hour and second is minutes whenever user enter value in hours then i convert hour into minutes and update minutes input box,when user enter minutes in minutes input box then i convert minutes into hours and update hour input box.

```
private  ignoreDateUpdates=true;        
this.form.get('ageMonths').valueChanges.subscribe(m => {
        if (ignoreDateUpdates) {
        ignoreDateUpdates = false;
        <code to set DateSelectorValue>
         }
        else{
      ignoreDateUpdates = true;
         }       
 });
    this.form.get('dateOfBirth').valueChanges.subscribe(
    dob => {
        if (ignoreDateUpdates) {
        ignoreDateUpdates = false;
        <code to set MonthsInput>
       }
        else{
        ignoreDateUpdates = true;
      }    
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the flag to false at the wrong time, so it does nothing. You set it to true and then to false almost right away. It will always be false when the second form control gets value changes.

Do this (for both controls):

```
this.form.get('dateOfBirth').valueChanges.subscribe(
  dob => {
      if (ignoreDateUpdates) {
        ignoreDateUpdates = false;
        return;
      };
      ignoreDateUpdates = true;
      <code to set MonthsInput>
  });
```